# How to change the image of the paypal "Buy Now" button using Classic API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I followed this tuts and generated dynamically generated and encrypted Buy Now Button. But Can I change the button image by passing any arguments ?

I could change it using JS / jQuery on the client side but I want to avoid this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BMUpdateButton](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMUpdateButton_API_Operation_NVP/) API to update the PayPal button image with your image URL.
Use

`BUTTONIMAGEURL` - To change the button image

`BUTTONIMAGE` - To change the size of button.